# In Infinity Blade 2, when is the right time to take on Bog Giant and Moss Golem?

Tags: infinity-blade-2

Currently I have 3000 life, a sword that can inflict 100+ damage and shield that takes 70+ damage.
Despite having those, its really tough to kill Bog Giant and the life left in me after the fight makes it impossible to take on Moss Golem. I have completed the game, that is I freed the worker and got myself imprisoned, but I cant kill these two.
I am in my 8th rebirth. Am I playing really poor or is the difficulty apt to my stats?
And what do you think is best equipment, sword and shield or dual or heavy? I think heavy sucks. I have 700 damage weapon but I cant defend/dodge with it when fighting with these 2 big guys.
What do you guys say?

Comment: Try to make a lot of great gems. Right now I have a 300% gem drop and 137% rare drop on my helm to help get gems. I have a 366 damage fire gem on my infinity blade which helps a lot. And I would also recommend using a healing ring as well, because none of my rings are doing any damage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If defeating these guys is pretty important to you, spend the extra 40 or 50 k (depending on how far in you are) on a large health regen potion. This makes the first battle easier and puts the focus on the second (it stops after the first battle and doesn't give time in the second).

For the vile blade 45k isn't really asking much. I would suggest dual-wielding for this battle, considering shields are rendered obsolete due to the bog giant/moss Golem's high level of block breakage. In addition to that, make sure your ring has a health or at least shield attack, because these guys hit hard no matter how good you are at dodging or parrying.

Comment: Thats what I did at the end. Health Regen 100 per sec. Was full health by the time I took down bog giant. After a few tries, I get the other one too. What a relief it was! Vile blade did the job for me.

Answer (score 1):

You cn restart at rebirth 1 in the options.

This will help you to raise your stats. I think I had much better stats the first time I restarted at rebirth1 but cannot remember for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a rebirth 11 with a 300+ damage sword and the same type of shield, and I can defeat them both, yet I can defeat the god king so you're fine, just keep upgrading your sword.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot about him until I did a lot of other stuff like treasure maps. I had the infinity blade with a 300 shock attack, (try maps/clashmobs for this). He was fairly easy.

Also, I suggest you get a high level healing + high level magic (so you can rapid heal). Then just try to  get a high level movement for a lot of dodging (or shield if its to inconvenient) and just go ahead and try to break and hit.